# Setting Flask-Cache memoization value

Tags: python, flask, memoization, flask-cache

If I have a function with the @cache.memoized decorator, is it possible to add a key-value pair to its caching without calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Looking at [memoize](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/blob/master/flask_cache/__init__.py#L520) in the Flask-Cache source, you can see the following code will let you set the cached return value for a function.

```
from app import cache

def set_memoized_cache(f, rv, *args, **kwargs):
    key = f.make_cache_key(f.uncached, *args, **kwargs)
    cache.set(key, rv, timeout=f.cache_timeout)
```

Where `f` is the wrapped function whose cached values you want to change, `rv` is the return value you want to set, and `*args` and `**kwargs` are the arguments you'd like the caching to apply for.